# Jquery only works with firebug (No console.log()) in my code

Tags: jquery, firefox, console, firebug

This card is suppose to animate a card flip. It works in all browsers except FF, even ie8. It'll only work with Firefox when firebug is open. I dont have console.log() in it so i am curious as to why it doesnt work. Here is my code and thanks for your help.

```
var margin = $("#image1").width() / 2;
var width = $("#image1").width();
var height = $("#image1").height();
var margin = $("#image3").width() / 2;
var width = $("#image3").width();
var height = $("#image3").height();
var margin = $("#image5").width() / 2;
var width = $("#image5").width();
var height = $("#image5").height();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image2").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
        opacity: '0.5'
    });
    $("#reflection2").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px'
    });
    $("#reveal").click(function() {
        $("#image1").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image2").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });
    $("#image2").click(function() {
        $("#image2").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image1").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });

    $("#image4").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
        opacity: '0.5'
    });
    $("#reflection2").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px'
    });
    $("#reveal").click(function() {
        $("#image3").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image4").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });
    $("#image4").click(function() {
        $("#image4").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image3").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });

    $("#image6").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
        opacity: '0.5'
    });
    $("#reflection2").stop().css({
        width: '0px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px'
    });
    $("#reveal").click(function() {
        $("#image5").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image6").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });
    $("#image6").click(function() {
        $("#image6").stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#image5").stop().animate({
                width: '' + width + 'px',
                height: '' + height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try installing another Javascript debugger for Firefox (i.e. not Firebug) and see if that reports any Javascript errors.

Comment: That code is copy paste happy. And do you realize you keep writing over width/height. yikes.

Comment: well, that makes very little sense to me. After the page has loaded in FF (without the animation), go to either tools->error console or web developer->error console, depending on what version of FF you use. Let me know what it says

Comment: yea im a jquery noob i this code from a site and had to try and edit myself.

Comment: @phillipschmidt there is no errors in the error console.

Comment: @KennethAshley and what exactly happens when you load it? (no firebug)

Comment: @phillipschmidth I click a button and the images are suppose to flip. However when no firebug is loaded no animation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Lint](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Lint) and see what errors show up with Firebug turned on. Include it in your markup right after jQuery, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.lint.js"></script>
```